# Running total... with a twist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out the SQL to do a running total for a daily quota system.  The system works like this...

Each day a user gets a quota of 2 "consumable things".  If they use them all up, the next day they get another 2.  If they somehow over use them (use more than 2), the next day they still get 2 (they can't have a negative balance).  If they don't use them all, the remainder carries to the next day (which can carry to the next, etc...).

Here is a chart of data to use as validation.  It's laid out as quota for the day, amount used that day, amount left at the end of the day:

```
2 - 2 - 0
2 - 0 - 2
4 - 3 - 1
3 - 0 - 3
5 - 7 - 0
2 - 1 - 1
3 - 0 - 3
5 - 2 - 3
5 - 1 - 4
6 - 9 - 0
```

The SQL to start of with would be:

```
WITH t(x, y) AS (
  VALUES (2, '2013-09-16'),
              (0, '2013-09-17'),
              (3, '2013-09-18'),
              (0, '2013-09-19'),
              (7, '2013-09-20'),
              (1, '2013-09-21'),
              (0, '2013-09-22'),
              (2, '2013-09-23'),
              (1, '2013-09-24'),
              (9, '2013-09-25')
)
```

For the life of me, trying recursive with statements and window aggregates, I cannot figure out how to make it work (but I can certainly see the pattern).

It should be something like 2 - x + SUM(previous row), but I don't know how to put that in to SQL.

Comment: you should fix your system where they can't *game* the system and go over quota, that would be the best solution. Doing things in multiple passes would make this simpler and easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Can't change the system... The ability to go over quota is a fact of life that just had to be worked in to the equation.

Comment: Why don't you just have a system whereby a user gets given 2 consumable items each day and you just have a single column keeping track of their consumable items.

Comment: then why have a quota system it isn't enforceable, sounds like it is just adding complexity with no benefit? this can be made much simpler, but just saying you get 2 a day, regardless of what happened yesterday, because you can't control what is happening anyway is seems.

Comment: I know 2 things only... The standard daily quota, and every time one is used.  I can figure out how many are used at any time, but trying to figure out the proper balance remaining is the issue because of the carry-over and possible over-use.  Really, the fact that they can go over quota is what throws my attempts off.  Solving that isn't as simple as just GREATEST(0, x).

Comment: Arguing over the quota system will not solve my problem.  It cannot change.

Comment: Have you tried creating custom aggregate function to do the calculations?

Comment: Shouldn't last row begin with 6 not 7?

Comment: Yes, good catch.  Not sure what happened to my math there... Likely due to time wasted trying to work this out!

Comment: The "+SUM(previous row)" part looks like a good candidate for LAG(). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating custom aggregate function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION quota_calc_func(numeric, numeric, numeric) -- carry over, daily usage and daily quota
RETURNS numeric AS 
$$
  SELECT GREATEST(0, $1 + $3 - $2);
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE quota_calc( numeric, numeric ) -- daily usage and daily quota
(
    SFUNC = quota_calc_func,
    STYPE = numeric,
    INITCOND = '0'
);

WITH t(x, y) AS (
  VALUES (2, '2013-09-16'),
              (0, '2013-09-17'),
              (3, '2013-09-18'),
              (0, '2013-09-19'),
              (7, '2013-09-20'),
              (1, '2013-09-21'),
              (0, '2013-09-22'),
              (2, '2013-09-23'),
              (1, '2013-09-24'),
              (9, '2013-09-25')
)
SELECT x, y, quota_calc(x, 2) over (order by y)
FROM t;
```

May contain bugs, haven't tested it.

Comment: Tried it - exactly what I was expecting as output.  I'm hoping that there is also a solution that doesn't require defining functions, but if not this is the answer.  I'll mark it as such after leaving this open a bit longer for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

> they can't have a negative balance

That triggered my memory :-)

I had a similar problem >10 years ago on a Teradata system.

The logic could be easily implemented using recursion, for each row do:

> add 2 "new" and substract x "used" quota, if this is less than zero
>   use zero instead.

I can't remember how i found that solution, but i finally implemented it using simple cumulative sums:

```
SELECT
  dt.*, 
  CASE -- used in following calculation, this is just for illustration
     WHEN MIN(quota_raw) OVER (ORDER BY datecol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) >= 0 THEN 0 
     ELSE MIN(quota_raw) OVER (ORDER BY datecol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  END AS correction,
  quota_raw
  - CASE
       WHEN MIN(quota_raw) OVER (ORDER BY datecol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) >= 0 THEN 0 
       ELSE MIN(quota_raw) OVER (ORDER BY datecol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    END AS quote_left
FROM
 (
   SELECT quota, datecol, 
      SUM(quota) OVER (ORDER BY datecol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS quota_used,
      2*COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY datecol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS quota_available,
      quota_available - quota_used AS quota_raw 
   FROM t
 ) AS dt
ORDER BY datecol
```

The secret sauce is the moving min "correction" which adjusts negative results to zero.

Comment: Didn't try your example exactly as typed, but how can you reference a column you create in the same select statement (ie, what you're doing with "correction")?

Comment: +1, good one, I've added a bit similar implementation to my answer also

Comment: sorry, i modified my existing query and moved the correction calculation into a column so it's easier to understand. And i always tend to forget that reusing an alias is only working on Teradata. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

simple recursive cte solution, assuming you have no gaps in dates:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select
        t.dt,
        2 as quote_day,
        t.quote_used,
        greatest(2 - t.quote_used, 0) as quote_left
    from t
    where t.dt = '2013-09-16'
    union all
    select
        t.dt,
        2 + c.quote_left as quote_day,
        t.quote_used,
        greatest(2 + c.quote_left - t.quote_used, 0) as quote_left
    from cte as c
        inner join t on t.dt = c.dt + 1  
)
select *
from cte
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3348f/2)</kbd>**

another solution - with cumulative aggregates:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        dt, quote_used,
        sum(2 - quote_used) over(order by dt asc) as quote_raw
    from t
), cte2 as (
    select
        dt, quote_used, quote_raw,
        least(min(quote_raw) over(order by dt asc), 0) as quote_corr
    from cte1
)
select
    dt,
    quote_raw - quote_corr + quote_used as quote_day,
    quote_used,
    quote_raw - quote_corr as quote_left
from cte2
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3348f/20)</kbd>**

Comment: There can be gaps.  If no items are used in a day, there are no entries for that day.

Comment: What is the expected result when there are gaps? Simply assume +2 for each day? This can be done doing a difference the current value and the MIN value.