# SQL view, new column based on last row with calculation

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance for the attention. I have a table with the structure as shown below. I need a third column, this for the first indice must be (4250 + valores), but from the second indice, must be the back result, plus second indice valores, with the condition: if the sum if greater than 4250, then the third column for this indice must be 4250, in order to sum this import for the next indice.

Below the example in Excel

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtEkAF7ffIsqg8QxJ_vUuiBgTL98uQ?e=WM7JEg

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, as formatted text (not images.) Also read [mcve] - make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Hey Kevin, in your excel I see alot of value in third row that are bigger than 4250. And you said: "if the sum if greater than 4250, then the third column for this indice must be 4250"

Comment: Hi @zip the column which i wanted got is Result, cause that have the condition, the column Result_without_condition is i have today.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18900231/2527905)

```
Result_without_condition -
Max(Greatest(CASE WHEN index > 1 
                  THEN Result_without_condition - 4250 
                  ELSE 0 
             END,0))
Over (ORDER BY index
      ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
```

Edit:

Based on your comment you didn't calculate `Result_without_condition`, yet, Then you need a nested calculation:

```
SELECT dt.*,
   result_without_condition
     - Max(Greatest(CASE WHEN "index" > 1 THEN Result_without_condition - 4250 ELSE 0 END,0))
       Over (ORDER BY "index"
             ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
FROM
 (
   SELECT tab.*,
      Sum("value")
      Over (ORDER BY "index"
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) 
      + 4250 AS Result_without_condition
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: I didnt explain correctly, the third and fourth columns in the excel are my expected result, but the calculation must be do with values column, by the way ur answer give me a idea, can find the calculation for the fist row: select indice, valores, resultado_2 from  (select i1.indice, i1.valores, i2.resultado as resultado_2 
from indice as i1 left join (select indice, valores +4250  as resultado, 
row_number() Over(ORDER BY indice asc ) as nuevo from  indice where indice = 1 group by indice, valores ) i2 on i1.indice = i2.indice ) total group by indice , valores , resultado_2 order by indice

Comment: Now i need to fin the wat to calculate 4266 - 500 and is this result is greater than 4250, then 4250 will be the result for this new calculation.